# How can we get selected text index in UITextView in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I am having struggle to find out the selected text index of a `UITextView`. In below picture I have select some text and I am getting selected text but I want to know the that selected text index. Please give any idea. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected range from the textView and then get the index from there. The code below is not tested but pulled from my memory.

```
let textViewRange = myTextView.selectedRange
let startIndex = textViewRange.location
let endIndex = startIndex + textViewRange.length
```